# Rails: filling out form values using a hash

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms

I am using a hash to fill out some forms. One of them is the user information. I am using this Hash successfully in the user registration form. The idea was to use the same Hash to fill out the edit form, as follows:

```
<% NEW_USER_HASH.each do |column_name,field_info|  %>
    <div class="field">
      <% if field_info["type"] != "hidden_field" %>
          <%= f.label field_info["label"] %>
      <% end %>
      <%= f.send(field_info["type"].to_sym, column_name , :value => @user.column_name) %>
    </div>
<% end %>
```

But I am getting the following error message:

```
undefined method `column_name'
```

I tried the following variations with the same results:

```
:value => @user.column_name.to_s
:value => @user.column_name.to_sym
```

Any ideas?

## ANSWER:

column_name is not an @user method, so the answer is to use the send method, with the variable column_name as a parameter.

So, replace:

```
:value => @user.column_name
```

With

```
:value => @user.send(column_name)
```

Comment: Why wouldn't you just use a `User` object and use the existing form mechanism?

Comment: Using the User object and the existing form mechanism does not work for me because some of the columns are actually JSON objects that I need to parse and use the values to generate form fields (dropdowns, radio buttons) based on the values inside the JSON objects.

Comment: And you'd rather do that in a template, instead of in Ruby where it's trivially testable? Hmm. Okay. Good luck!

Comment: @EastsideDeveloper Can you show an example of what is in the `NEW_USER_HASH`? And try `column_name.to_s` .

Comment: Here's the sample from NEW_USER_HASH:

NEW_USER_HASH[ "first" ] = { "label" => FIRST_STR, "type" => "text_field" }

I've already tried column_name.to_s and column_name.to_sym (please see my question)

Comment: I agree with Dave.  Going around the rails conventions is up to you, but you'll just run into one problem after another and it's basically an exercise is something (futility comes to mind).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the culprit is `@user.column_name`. One way is to use eval("@user." + column_name). Better way is what I have shown below.

Try this:

```
<% NEW_USER_HASH.each do |column_name,field_info|  %>
    <div class="field">
      <% if field_info["type"] != "hidden_field" %>
          <%= f.label field_info["label"] %>
      <% end %>
      <%= f.send(field_info["type"].to_sym, column_name , :value => @user.send(column_name)) %>
    </div>
<% end %>
```

Let me know if this works.

Good luck!

Comment: This does not work. What I get is the following error: no method name given. If I change it to: @user.column_name.send, I get the following error: undefined method 'column_name'

Comment: @EastsideDeveloper Sorry, typo. Please try again.

Comment: yes, this works. Thank you. I will update the original question.